# TFS 2010: how to add a new user?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I just installed **TFS Server 2010** on Windows 7 Ultimate.

I even managed to connect to the TFS server using Visual Studio 2010 - I didn't have to enter any login and password, as Windows Authentication was automatically used.

Now I need to add a new user to TFS, with a specific login and password, so that a member of the project could access the TFS server from the Internet.

However, I did not find a way to **add a new user to TFS**!

I used to work with Visual SourceSafe, and there the management of users was quite straightforward.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little weird in non-domain situations.

1. Create a new local user on your computer.
2. In Visual Studio, look on the `Team` menu for `Team Project Collection` settings
3. Add that new user to the `Authorized Users` group (I think-- I'm not able to access mine right now, so I'm not sure what it's called.  It's something like that, though).
4. On the `Team` menu, find `Team Project Settings`
5. Add the same user to the `Contributors` group.

When the other user logs on, they will have to specify the TFS Application Tier computer as the domain name.  For example, if you installed TFS on a computer named `MyWin7Box`, they would sign on as `MyWin7Box\Username`

Comment: That seems to work - thanks, Robaticus!

I have another question: is the only way of adding users to TFS is to create them as Windows users? In VSS, users are only VSS-local-users - not "global" Windows users. Can I create TFS-only users in TFS?

And one of the strange things of this approach is that in the New Bug window in the "Assigned To" list I can see even the "LOCAL SERVICE" user - which seems totally stupid! Can something be done about that?

Comment: You need to do a little bit of workitem type editing.  This help from  a while back should still be valid:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404871%28VS.80%29.aspx